# How to count sequentially using letters instead of numbers?

Tags: python

Is there a simple way to count using letters in Python? Meaning, 'A' will be used as 1, 'B' as 2 and so on, and after 'Z' will be 'AA', 'AB' and so on. So below code would generate:

```
def get_next_letter(last_letter):
    return last_letter += 1  # pseudo

>>> get_next_letter('a')
'b'
>>> get_next_letter('b')
'c'
>>> get_next_letter('c')
'd'
...
>>> get_next_letter('z')
'aa'
>>> get_next_letter('aa')
'ab'
>>> get_next_letter('ab')
'ac'
...
>>> get_next_letter('az')
'ba'
>>> get_next_letter('ba')
'bb'
...
>>> get_next_letter('zz')
'aaa'
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. What do you mean by "population"? What does this have to do with letters?

Comment: Are you trying to "increment" a string from `"a"` to `"b"` to `"z"`, then to `"aa"`, etc.? If so, I suggest asking that as clearly as possible instead of using words like "population" without any context.

Comment: It's easy to write using `itertools.count`, `itertools.product`, and a generator function named `population`. `x = population(); next(x); next(x); ...`.

Comment: Do you *need* to find the successor of an arbitrary string, or is this just your attempt at generating the infinite sequence of such strings?

Comment: If you are trying to do a base-26 number system, it might make more sense to have `a` be `0` so that the successor of `z` would be `ba` (just like the successor of 9 is 10 in base 10).

Comment: @hewi please note that the answer you accepted (which is now deleted) didn't actually work properly for many cases

Comment: luckily I saved it, as it was the perfect solution

Comment: @hewi How could it be the perfect solution when `getNextPopulation('ab') = 'aac'` (as Tomerikoo correctly points out)? Doubtless it might debug into the perfect solution, but it isn't there yet.

Comment: @JohnColeman judging by the fact that the answer was deleted by a mod (and clues from the wording of the answer) I suspect this was another victim of a ChatGPT answer (which is another good example why it is now forbidden...)

Answer (score 4):

Based on [@Charlie Clark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2385133/charlie-clark)'s implementation of the [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) util [`get_column_letter`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/utils/cell.html#get_column_letter), we can have:

```py
def get_number_letter(n):
    letters = []
    while n > 0:
        n, remainder = divmod(n, 26)
        # check for exact division and borrow if needed
        if remainder == 0:
            remainder = 26
            n-= 1
        letters.append(chr(remainder+64))
    return ''.join(reversed(letters))
```

This gives the letter representation of a number. Now, to increment, we need the reverse. Based on that logic (and the general number base logic), I wrote:

```py
def number_from_string(letters):
    n = 0
    for i, c in enumerate(reversed(letters)):
        n += (ord(c)-64)*26**i
    return n
```

And now we can combine them to:

```py
def get_next_letter(letters):
    return get_number_letter(number_from_string(letters)+1)
```

---

Original answer:

This kind of "counting" is very similar to how Excel indexes its columns. Therefore it is possible to take advantage of the [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package, which has two utility functions: [`get_column_letter`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.utils.cell.html#openpyxl.utils.cell.get_column_letter) and [`column_index_from_string`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.utils.cell.html#openpyxl.utils.cell.column_index_from_string):

```py
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter, column_index_from_string

def get_next_letter(letters):
    return get_column_letter(column_index_from_string(letters)+1)
```

***NOTE:*** as this is based on Excel, it is limited to count up-to `'ZZZ'`. i.e. calling the function with `'ZZZ'` will raise an exception.

---

Output example for both implementations:

```
>>> get_next_letter('A')
'B'
>>> get_next_letter('Z')
'AA'
>>> get_next_letter('BD')
'BE'
```

Comment: Does this supply an arbitrary number of sequences, though? Excel spreadsheets, I thought, have a maximum number of columns. (In any case, `openpyxl` would be a pretty heavy dependency for something simple like this.)

Comment: @chepner Good points. Indeed regarding the first the limit I found was up-to `'ZZZ'`... Regarding the second that's true as well, it's just the first thing that came to mind when I saw this sequence so seemed like a nice reuse

Comment: @chepner I took the original implementation of the Excel and removed the limitation :)

Comment: OK, yeah, I figured `column_index_from_string` probably only worked for the valid column names, not arbitrary strings :)

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with the simple special case of getting just the single-character strings.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase


def population():
    yield from ascii_lowercase
```

Then

```
>>> x = population()
>>> list(x)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
>>> x = population()
>>> next(x)
'a'
>>> next(x)
'b'
```

So we'd like to add the two-character sequences next:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from itertools import product


def population():
    yield from ascii_lowercase
    yield from map(''.join, product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=2)
```

Note that the single-character strings are just a special case of the product with `repeat=1`, so we could have written

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from itertools import product


def population():
    yield from map(''.join, product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=1)
    yield from map(''.join, product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=2)
```

We can write this with a loop:

```
def population():
    for k in range(1, 3):
        yield from map(''.join, product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=k)
```

but we don't necessarily want an artificial upper limit on what strings we can produce; we want, in theory, to produce *all* of them. For that, we replace `range` with `itertools.count`.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from itertools import product, count


def population():
    for k in count(1):
        yield from map(''.join, product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=k)
```

Comment: While this is an elegant idea, it doesn't allow for any easy successor function, which is what OP is asking for. On the other hand, maybe it answers the question that they meant to ask.

Comment: Ah, I somehow ignored that the requested function took the previous state as an argument. (Or rather, I assumed that the function was just an attempt at producing the desired sequence, rather than indicating a need to start the sequence at an arbitrary point.)

Answer (score 0):

all proposed are just way too complicated
I came up with below, using a recursive call,
this is it!

```
def getNextLetter(previous_letter):
    """ 
        'increments' the provide string to the next letter recursively
        raises TypeError if previous_letter is not a string 
        returns "a" if provided previous_letter was emtpy string
    """
    if not isinstance(previous_letter, str):
        raise TypeError("the previous letter should be a letter, doh")
    if previous_letter == '':
        return "a"
    for letter_location in range(len(previous_letter) - 1, -1, -1):
        if previous_letter[letter_location] == "z":
            return getNextLetter(previous_letter[:-1])+"a"
        else:
            return (previous_letter[:-1])+chr(ord(previous_letter[letter_location])+1)

# EOF
```