# sequential counting using letters instead of numbers

Tags: python

I need a method that 'increments' the string a to z and than aa to az and then ba to bz and so on, like the columns in an excel sheet.  I will feed the method the previous string and it should increment to the next letter.

```
PSEUDO CODE

def get_next_letter(last_letter):
    return last_letter += 1
```

So I could use it like so:

```
>>> get_next_letter('a')
'b'
>>> get_next_letter('b')
'c'
>>> get_next_letter('c')
'd'
...
>>> get_next_letter('z')
'aa'
>>> get_next_letter('aa')
'ab'
>>> get_next_letter('ab')
'ac'
...
>>> get_next_letter('az')
'ba'
>>> get_next_letter('ba')
'bb'
...
>>> get_next_letter('zz')
'aaa'
```

Comment: How about you post the code you've made this attempt with, and we can go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all proposed are just way too complicated
I came up with below, using a recursive call,
this is it!

```
def getNextLetter(previous_letter):
    """ 
        'increments' the provide string to the next letter recursively
        raises TypeError if previous_letter is not a string 
        returns "a" if provided previous_letter was emtpy string
    """
    if not isinstance(previous_letter, str):
        raise TypeError("the previous letter should be a letter, doh")
    if previous_letter == '':
        return "a"
    for letter_location in range(len(previous_letter) - 1, -1, -1):
        if previous_letter[letter_location] == "z":
            return getNextLetter(previous_letter[:-1])+"a"
        else:
            characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
            return (previous_letter[:-1])\
                   +characters[characters.find(previous_letter[letter_location])+1]

# EOF
```

Comment: This `characters[characters.find(previous_letter[letter_location])+1]` is simply `chr(ord(previous_letter[letter_location])+1)`. No need for the `characters` string

Answer (score 3):

I believe there are better ways to handle this, but you can implement the algorithm for adding two numbers on paper...

```
def get_next_letter(string):
    x = list(map(ord, string)) # convert to list of numbers
    x[-1] += 1 # increment last element
    result = '' 
    carry = 0;
    for c in reversed(x):
        result = chr((c + carry )) + result # i'm not accounting for when 'z' overflows here
        carry = c > ord('z')
    if carry: # add the new letter at the beggining in case there is still carry
        result = 'a' + result
    return result.replace('{', 'a') # replace overflowed 'z' with 'a'
```

Answer (score 3):

I fact what you want to achieve is increment a number expressed in base26 (using the 26 alphabet letters as symbols).

We all know decimal base that we use daily.
We know hexadecimal that is in fact base16 with symbols including digits and a, b, c, d, e, f.
Example : 0xff equals 15.

An approach is to convert into base10, increment the result decimal number, then convert it back to base26.
Let me explain.

I define 2 functions.

A first function to convert a string (base26) into a base10 (decimal) number.
`str_tobase10("abcd")  # 19010`

The inverse function to convert a base10 number (decimal) to a string (base26).
`base10_tostr(19010)  # abcd`

`get_next_letter()` just has to convert the string to a number, increment by one and converts back to a string.

Advantages :

- pure Python, no extra lib/dependency required.
- works with very long strings

Example :
`get_next_letter("abcdefghijz")  # abcdefghika`

```py
def str_tobase10(value: str) -> int:
    n = 0
    for letter in value:
        n *= 26
        n += ord(letter)-ord("a")+1
    return n

def base10_tostr(value: int) -> str:
    s = ""
    n = value
    while n > 26:
        r = n % 26
        s = chr(ord("a")-1+r) + s
        n = n // 26   
    return chr(ord("a")-1+n) + s

def get_next_letter(value: str):
    n = str_tobase10(value)
    return base10_tostr(n+1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable)'s [`get_column_letter`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.utils.cell.html#openpyxl.utils.cell.get_column_letter) and [`column_index_from_string`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.utils.cell.html#openpyxl.utils.cell.column_index_from_string)

```
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter, column_index_from_string
# or `from openpyxl.utils.cell import get_column_letter, column_index_from_string`

def get_next_letter(s: str) -> str: 
    return get_column_letter(
        column_index_from_string(s) + 1
    ).lower()
```

and then

```
>>> get_next_letter('aab')
'aac'
>>> get_next_letter('zz')
'aaa'
```

?

---

*Keeping in mind that this solution only works in [[A, ZZZ](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/utils/cell.html#get_column_letter:%7E:text=indicies%20corrospond%20to-,A%20%2D%3E%20ZZZ,-and%20include%20all)[.*

Comment: dont want to  add dependecies

Comment: Right @hewi. Depending on your big picture intention, openpyxl may be of great help for other things as well.

Comment: This only works until `ZZZ` (see my answer on the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74732081/6045800)...)

Comment: @Tomerikoo indeed. This is actually [explicited in the source code](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/utils/cell.html#get_column_letter:~:text=indicies%20corrospond%20to-,A%20%2D%3E%20ZZZ,-and%20include%20all), as comment though. Thx.